# html canvas pixel buffer

Tags: html, canvas, redraw

I don't know the correct term, but in GTK I believe it was called a pixel buffer. You could copy all or some of the drawing area to a pixbuf, and then later dump the pixbuf back to the screen, rather than going through and rendering the entire thing all over again. I am implementing a menubar, and the menubar drops down and occludes everything underneath it. However, it takes a few seconds to draw the entire canvas, so I was wondering if there is a correct way to copy everything that will be occluded by the drop down menu, then when the drop down menu is closed, redraw it to the screen. I imagine this can be done with the `context.getImageData()` function, but I have read that it is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Yes, `getImageData()` is pretty slow, but I don't think you can get any faster then the native implementation. I guess you better off writting a class to handle the graphics on the canvas as objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true, `getImageData()` is far too inefficient. But there's a better start for specifically what you're trying to do:

With canvas context's `drawImage` method, you can pass in an image but you can also pass in another canvas. So construct a temp canvas that will never be added to the page:

```
// only exists in javascript, not on the page
tempcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
tempcanvas.height = (normal canvas width);
tempcanvas.width = (normal canvas height);
```

Then you can call `tempcanvasContext.drawImage(normalCanvas, 0, 0)` to take a snapshot of the current canvas right before the drop down menu is created. When the drop down menu disappears, you call `normalcanvasContext.drawImage(tempcanvas, 0, 0)` to draw it back.

I hope this gives a good general idea, and it should be much faster than `getImageData`. You can make it even more efficient by only copying the exact portions of the screen you want to redraw.

Comment: Thanx, I'll give that a try. Unfortunately, one can not specify what subset of the tempcanvas one wants to use. That would be much more helpful.